# Easy way to merge two Xcode project files that contain different targets (Carbon/Cocoa/PPC/Intel)

Tags: xcode, macos, photoshop

We have two Xcode project files for a Photoshop Plug-in. One for PS CS2 through CS5 32-Bit and the other for CS5 64-Bit and CS6. I'll not mention PS Elements etc. For CS and PS 7.0 we maintain a separate Codewarrior project - Well, mainly for sports today.

Anyway the PPC plug-in for CS2 and the Universal Binary plug-in (PPC/Intel 32-Bit) are built from one Xcode Project and the 64-Bit Cocoa UI plug-in is built from another Xcode Project. Simply because Adobe never provided an example with 64-Bit and PPC in the same project file. They always just break the old version support in the SDK to fix things for the current PS.

We made it so that all source files are completely interoperable. Just a bunch of #defines control what SDK PC/MAC_CW/MAC_XC/MAC_XC64 we're in and things work. So my question is if there is any easy way to merge the two  Xcode Project files so that one contains all targets? It'd be limited to being used with 10.6 of course because of the PPC versions but still I was wondering how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I delve into the merging, you might also want to consider: programmatically building from the command line using `xcodebuild` for automating the build of all of the individual projects as opposed to merging them, or using Workspaces to contain both projects.   I'm not sure if Workspaces is an option in 10.6, though, so that might not work.

Based on your description above (most notably that you are using all of the same files in both projects), I would suggest choosing one of the existing projects and then just duplicating the existing target and modifying it to work for your alternate build requirements.

We have tried to do programmatic and scripted merges of Xcode files in the past and it is often not worth the hassle because the Xcode project files are pretty brittle and contain a lot of complex file references which aren't easy to de-duplicate.

Process would be:

1. Open the project file you want to use as your final project
2. Select top level project in the Project Navigator (which should make the Project appear in the main area
3. Select your current target
4. Choose *Edit > Duplicate*
5. With the new target, adjust the settings as necessary, taking special care about: Product Name, Deployment Target, etc.
6. Remove the libraries which aren't necessary for this platform from the list of link objects in the Build Phases tab
7. Add the additional libraries to the project using *File > Add Files...*
8. Add the libraries to the Target's Build Phases (link)

It'll be a bit tedious, but it'll give you better results than trying to do this programmatically.

Comment: Thank you very much for this extensive answer to my question.